# HTML5 Body Map in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an ASP.Net Web Forms project part of which records accidents/events.  It's been requested that a body map is available whereby users can select body parts from it to mark where injuries have occurred.

Has anyone any idea of anything that already exists that I can look at? Also whether anyone has had any past experience of needing to do something similar and can recommend whether it would be better to use Canvas/WebGL or simple images with mapping for individual parts?

Comment: What does that mean: "a body map is available whereby users can select body parts from it to mark where injuries have occurred"?? May be Google Maps API could help you but Stack is better at helping with code than general requirements.

Comment: Off-topic if asking for an external resource or...simply too broad. What are you trying to do? Is a simple image with `<map>` enough?

Comment: @frenchie Imagine a picture of the human body (external) where you can hover over eyes, mouth, neck, chest etc and click on them.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Ah ok, I may remove then, anywhere else I could ask the question? If you see my comment back to frenchie above that is what I'm trying to do so <map> may be enough but hoping I can save alot of dev time with a pre-existing solution if possible.

Comment: I don't where you can find a ready-to-use image map for `<map>` but it shouldn't be such time consuming if areas are (mostly) rectangular. BTW if injury may be on eyes then don't forget to make your site accessible (graphics are seldom welcome for screen readers).

Comment: They aren't unfortunately and the head alone needs to have 11-15 maps which could be mostly rects but likely polys.  Need to do full body hence I'm hoping to find something.  I expect I will end up doing it that way but wondered if someone may have drawn the human body in HTML5 canvas as well that could be developed upon.